# Hibernate Criteria: inheritence: Get a list of only the root class entities

Tags: java, hibernate

Assume i have:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Child extends Parent{
}
```

How can i do a selection of only the instances saved as a Parent, not as a Child.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the bottom of [section 14.9 of the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where):

> The special property `class` accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value.

```
from Cat cat where cat.class = DomesticCat
```

So I believe in your case you could use the HQL constraint `... where class=Parent` to filter out the instances of `Child`.

Comment: Great! It worked:) Didn't see it in the docs. In Criteria i used c.add(Restrictions.eq("class", Parent.class));